# npm creating package.json in wrong location

Tags: npm, package.json, npm-init

I'm following [this tutorial](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file) to create a package.json file.

I navigate to my project and and run `npm init` but it always creates the package.json in a different location than where I navigated.

```
H:\>cd C:/Github/my_project/Styleguide/

H:\>npm init --yes
Wrote to H:\package.json:

{
  "name": "my-project",
etc...
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've tried different paths just for kicks, but it always puts the json in my H: drive.

Comment: The prompt of your command `npm init --yes` shows that you are still in `H:`

Comment: The `cd` command didn't worked, you should try to use ```\``` instead of `/` in your path on windows.

Comment: Wow. I need better eyes. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `> cd C:\etc...` I first had to do just `> C:` to navigate away from H: drive.